# How to format Highcharts columnRange to get json data for temperature Min and Max

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to display information on Highcharts from the forecast.io api. With the help of others on this site, I have figured out how to call the data using a simple line or area chart; however, I can't figure out how to with the columnRange chart. I want to display the daily min and max temperature forecast. So the top column would display today's min and max temp, and the next column would be tomorrows, and so on.

To call the min and max for today from forecast.io:

- data.daily.data[0].temperatureMin
- data.daily.data[0].temperatureMax

Tomorrows would have a "1" instead of a 0. The day after would have a "2".

I haven't been able to figure out how to make a function that does this for each day. I have a jsfiddile which includes my forecast.io API key. This is needed to call from the source.

Anyways, any help would be much appreciated! http://jsfiddle.net/nn51895/gjw9m1qo/2/

(my x axis labels are really messed up as you will see..)

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    xAxis: {

    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°F'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y + '°F';
                }
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Daily Min and Max',
        data: 'ChartData',
        pointStart: new Date().getTime(),
       pointInterval:90000000,

    }]

  });

});

$.ajax({
 url: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/87a7dd82a91b0b765d2576872f2a3826/53.479324,-2.248485",
 jsonp: "callback",
 dataType: "jsonp",
 success: function(chart) {

  var dataArr = new Array();
   var height = chart.xAxis[0].height;
  var pointRange = chart.daily.data[0].temperatureMax - chart.daily.data[0].temperatureMin;
   var max = chart.daily.data[0].temperatureMax;
   var min = chart.daily.data[0].temperatureMin;
   var pointCount = (max - min) / pointRange;
    var timeint = chart.daily.data[0].time; 
 for(var i=0; i<chart.daily.data.length; i++)
  dataArr.push(chart.daily.data[i].temperatureMin);

 plotChart(dataArr, timeint)


 }
 });
```

Comment: `chart` object from the ajax call doesn't have `xAxis` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as said in the comment:

```
success: function (chart) {
    ...
    var height = chart.xAxis[0].height;
}
```

You are trying to get for some unknown reason height of xAxis from the chart. Meanwhile you `chart` variable is referring to the data from AJAX call. I hope that's clear, so remove that line or change to:

```
success: function (chart) {

    var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var dataArr = new Array();
    var height = myChart.xAxis[0].height;
}
```

Second thing, that option:

```
        data: 'ChartData',
```

Is wrong, there should be an empty array, since Highcharts requires array for data, not some string:

```
        data: [],
```

Now, after fixing these bugs, you should go to [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange) and create the same data format. That's example for required format for Highcharts.

More about `series.data` can be found in [API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) - you need to read this.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback. I don't really understand the first part of your response. Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you saying that I can not use that xAxis in my AJAX call? Also,  I have read the API, but my data is not static. They don't provide much detail on how to include non-static data. I have figured that out, but haven't been able to include two data types, Low temperature data and High temperature data.

Comment: Of course you can, but you are using wrong variable to do it. In your code `chart` variable is referring to the data which comes from AJAX call.. as I said, remove that line (which does nothing) or replace with code I suggested. Difference between dynamic and static in **format** doesn't exist. You just need to prepare proper format for data which you will be using in Highcharts..

Comment: I see that makes sense. I wasn't sure where I was going wrong but I think I know what to do. Thank you